# Inserting Rows into a Table with Text Inputs

Tags: html, html-table, row, editing

I'm trying to insert a rows on a regular HTML table.

Each row has a `<input type="text">` element.

But each time I add a new row through JavaScript, the data or values contained on the already existing `<inputs>` disappear.

Here's the code:

```
<table id="tableSeriales" summary="Seriales" class="servicesT" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="servHd">Seriales</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="servBodL">
            <input id="0" type="text" value="" style="color: blue; width: 100%"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="javascript:addRow()">Add row</a>
```

And, the JavaScript looks like:

```
function addRow() {
        var rowCount = $('#tableSeriales tr').length;
        $("#tableSeriales").html(
                $("#tableSeriales").html() +
                '<tr><td class="servBodL"><input id="' + (rowCount +1) + '"type="text" value="" style="color: blue; width: 100%" onkeypress="return handleKeyPress(event,this.form)"/></td></tr>'
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$('html code goes here').appendTo('#tableSeriales');`

or `$('#tableSeriales').append('html code goes here');`